# Transform between /openni_depth_frame and /camera_link

Tags: ros, openi-tracker, ar-kinect, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I'm a bit confused since I'm new to ROS. I'm using the [openni_tracker](http://ros.org/wiki/openni_tracker) and [ar_kinect](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ar_kinect) packages together. Rviz complains that it can't transform from any of the skeleton topics (e.g. /head1) to /camera_depth_optical_frame (which is the fixed frame).

So I'm wondering how do I transform from /openni_depth_frame to /camera_link? /openni_depth_frame is the root of the tf tree for the skeleton produced by openni_tracker and /camera_link is the root of the tf tree for ar_kinect.

[This](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13590821653532752.jpg) is the output from "rosrun tf view_frames" so you can see the tf's that are running.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

James

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53326/transform-between-/openni_depth_frame-and-/camera_link/) by [James Diprose](https://answers.ros.org/users/3239/james-diprose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2013-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is that camera_depth_frame and openni_depth_frame are the same. You could test that with a static transform broadcaster between the two set to identity.

I'm not sure if there are any configuration options that will give you consistent frames.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [James Diprose](https://answers.ros.org/users/3239/james-diprose/) on 2013-01-28**:
Cheers mate, you're right. I changed the root frame in openni_tracker from /openni_depth_frame to /camera_depth_frame and the transformations now work and look right in Rviz